# Edit an Office document from a custom ASP.NET application in a SharePoint way

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, ms-office, httphandler

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application (.NET Framework 3.5) that allows users to download files. These users have to register in the application before being able to do any operation and are not linked with any Windows account. The application has a HTTP handler that triggers each time a user wants to download a file. That handler checks if the user has the permissions to do that operation and pushes the file.

When a user clicks on an Office document (doc, xls, ppt, etc.), the file is automatically downloaded (provided the user has the right permissions) and opened with the adequate program (Word, Excel or PowerPoint). Now, what I would like to do is allowing this user to edit that document and directly save it on the server from the external program without this user to upload it again via the web interface. Basically, I just want to have a behavior similar to what SharePoint does.

One requirement is that I don't have to use some browser plugin that displays a document inside a browser's window.

I currently don't know where to start nor what I really need.

**Edit**

Another requirement is not to use Office add-ins due to the large number of users (several thousands).

Comment: Do you have the possibility to install an Office AddIn on the clients computer? Then you could implement a custom functionality into the Office program itself to upload the file to your server.

Comment: @Rosenheimer The application has a quite large number of users (several thousands) and it is unreasonable for us to oblige them to install add-ins for Word, Excel and PowerPoint.

Comment: You need some way to tell the desktop application where to put the file. You could inclube VBA code in your files that override the Application Save method and provide a user dialog for uploading the files back to your server, but I don't know if it is possible for you to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an Office add-in which will provide end-users with custom UI that allows to save the file wherever you need (i.e. upload it on the server). For example, you may develop a custom at in the Backstage UI which can be shown under the Save/SaveAs tabs. See [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information.

See the [Create Add-ins and Customizations for Office by using Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620922.aspx) section in MSDN to get started quickly.

Comment: Thanks but as there are several thousands users, it is unreasonable to oblige them to install three add-ins for Office programs (Word, Excel and PowerPoint).